# More Synonym Movies

Tags: knowledge

Once you figure out [these](http://www.xkcd.com/1563/), try a few more.

> 1. The Nice, the Mean, and the Hideous
> 2. The Fourth Prime
> 3. The Linear Transformation
> 4. Psychotic Supremum: Stormy Street
> 5. Woman's
> 6. A Dozen Displeased Dudes
> 7. Missing Chest Thieves
> 8. The Second Period: 24-hour Evaluation
> 9. The Principal Panthera Leo
> 10. WeirdSex, MD: The process of apprehension removal and radioactive device appreciation

Whoever answers all / the final unanswered one gets the check mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The Nice, the Mean, and the Hideous

> The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly

2. The Fourth Prime

> Seven (or Se7en)

3. The Linear Transformation

> The Matrix

4. Psychotic Supremum: Stormy Street

> Mad Max: Fury Road (thanks, Roland!)

5. Woman's

> Her

6. A Dozen Displeased Dudes

> 12 Angry Men

7. Missing Chest Thieves

> Raiders of the Lost Ark

8. The Second Period: 24-hour Evaluation

> Terminator 2: Judgment Day

9. The Principal Panthera Leo

> The Lion King

10. WeirdSex, MD: The process of apprehension removal and radioactive device appreciation

> Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb (thanks, Vance!)

Comment: I'd bet that 10 is "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb"?

Comment: Mad Max: Fury Road - Psychotic supremum

Comment: Nice!  The [xkcd thread](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=112437) on this subject has many other examples.

Comment: My favorite is "Space Fights: The Scary Ghosts." :D